# How to use FTDI in C++ project?

Tags: c++, c, dll, ftdi

I tried to open serial connection using FTDI and their example.
No matter what I do I can't solve this error even after seeing lots of posts here about it.
This is the error I get:

```
error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__FT_GetComPortNumber@8 referenced in function _main
```

and this is my code (using FTD2XX.h from https://www.ftdichip.com website):

```js
#include "FTD2XX.h"

#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <Objbase.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <tchar.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "FTD2XX.lib")

int main()
{
    FT_HANDLE fthandle;
    FT_STATUS res;
    LONG COMPORT = -1;

    char COMx[5];
    int n;

    DCB dcb;
    HANDLE hCommPort = NULL;
    BOOL fSuccess;


    /***********************************************************************
    //Find the com port that has been assigned to your device.
    /***********************************************************************/

    res = FT_Open(0, &fthandle);

    if (res != FT_OK) {
        printf("opening failed! with error %d\n", res);
        return 1;
    }


    res = FT_GetComPortNumber(fthandle, &COMPORT);

    if (res != FT_OK) {
        printf("get com port failed %d\n", res);
        return 1;
    }

    if (COMPORT == -1) {
        printf("no com port installed \n");
    }

    else {
        printf("com port number is %d\n", COMPORT);
    }


    FT_Close(fthandle);


    /********************************************************/
    // Open the com port assigned to your device
    /********************************************************/

    n = sprintf_s(COMx, "COM%d", COMPORT);

    hCommPort = CreateFile(
        COMx,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL
    );

    if (hCommPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Help - failed to open\n");
        return(1);
    }


    printf("Hello World!\n");

    /********************************************************/
    // Configure the UART interface parameters
    /********************************************************/

    fSuccess = GetCommState(hCommPort, &dcb);


    if (!fSuccess) {
        printf("GetCommStateFailed %u \n", GetLastError());
        return (2);
    }

    //set parameters.
    dcb.BaudRate = 115200;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;

    fSuccess = SetCommState(hCommPort, &dcb);


    if (!fSuccess) {
        printf("SetCommStateFailed %u \n", GetLastError());
        return (3);
    }

    printf("Port configured \n");


    /********************************************************/
    // Writing data to the USB to UART converter
    /********************************************************/

    DWORD dwwritten = 0, dwErr;
    char data_out[12] = "HELLO WORLD";
    DWORD w_data_len = 12;


    fSuccess = WriteFile(hCommPort, &data_out, w_data_len, &dwwritten, NULL);


    if (!fSuccess) {
        dwErr = GetLastError();
        //printf("Write Failed \n", GetLastError());
        return (4);
    }

    printf("bytes written = %d\n", dwwritten);

    /********************************************************/
    //Reading data from the USB to UART converter
    /********************************************************/

    char buf[256];
    DWORD dwRead;

    memset(buf, 0, 256);


    if (ReadFile(hCommPort, buf, w_data_len, &dwRead, NULL)) {
        printf("data read = %s\n", buf);
    }

    /********************************************************/
    //Closing the device at the end of the program
    /********************************************************/


    CloseHandle(hCommPort);

    return 0;
}
```

**What I already did and haven't worked:**

- Changed linker to Dll
- Changed configuration type to console
- added path to dll in linker
- Changed to win23
- added .lib and .dll files to the actual project
- referenced files in project
- compress this project to dll project and using this in a new project

Comment: Which toolchain are you using? The example 5 from https://ftdichip.com/software-examples/code-examples/visual-c-examples/ seems to work just fine with VS2019. Btw, it is always good practice to be very specific about the source of the used code. IMHO, mixing D2XX calls with VCP acces is something one should avoid. But they provide such code as example. So welp.

Comment: what do you mean by toolchain? I'm using VS2022

Comment: Then check if you can import & compile the linked example no. 5.

Answer (score 0):

Since your first command of FT_Open runs, I suggest that your FTDI .dll was loaded correctly.

I won't recommend mixing D2XX with VCP since it will cause collision of the datastream. (Happened to me before so I simply turned off VCP and stick with d2xx lib.)

It seems like you have assigned an initial value for COMPORT, which defeat the purpose of COMPORT since it is a return value for the command to verify is the argument typed in correctly. Have you tried just declaring the variable?